# Let $I$ be a nilpotent left ideal of $R$. Prove that for each left $R$-module $M$, $IM\ll M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $I$ be a nilpotent left ideal of $R$. Prove that for each left $R$-module $M$, $IM\ll M$.  ($\ll$ means superfluous)

If $IM + N = M$, then $I^2M + IN + N = M$

I know we will use this information in somewhere but I dont know how to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t quit now!

From where you started notice  $M=I^2M + IN + N = I^2M+N$.

Repeating that again, $M=I^3M+N$.

You see where this is headed?

Comment: Are we going to do this n times? Thats what i see.

Comment: @BeratYILDIRIM yeah, that’ll do it.